# How to get the version and the encoding of a dbf file

Tags: c#, encoding, foxpro, dbf, dbase

I have a dbf file which contains text fields filled with Russian text.

How to find which particular encoding has been used in this file? Also, how to get whether it is dBase III, IV, 5.0, or it is FoxPro?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest `file` (or libmagic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can open the table, SYS(2029) will give you some clues about its origin. If you can't open it, look with a hex editor at the first byte of the file. The value there will tell you where it comes from. This article shows at least some of the values: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/sswxxbea%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Tamar